# Vector .reserve() and allocation efficiency (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I am trying to optimize the organisation of my projectile objects in my game.

I read that I should avoid allocation during game-runtime to avoid performance issues. So, if I initialize a vector with reserve(1000) at the beginning of the game state and add the Projectile objects during runtime via push_back(Projectile()); will that cause "allocation" or does it just fill the already allocated space with stuff and is superfast? ;D

Comment: It will be superfast since you do not ask for more than 1000 elements

Comment: It will be even faster when you use emplace_back as you then avoid a possible copy.

Comment: @Surt push_back support move semantic

Comment: What's a `projectile`? Is it movable? How many elements in the vector? `vector`, after all, offers amortized constant `push_back()`.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier, that is right, but faster than move is no move or copy at all, construction in place.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier, it is not `push_back`, it's the question of type having `move` trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your replys so far. To clarify: Projectile is a erm... well... "default" class. Does that implicate its move- and copyable? Since it HAS to be allocated right next to the other Projectiles in the vector to ensure minimum processing time while looping through all projectiles each game-tick, it should probably be movable and NOT be constructed in place i guess? Guess you can see that I lack pretty much experience. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different metodes of placing the projectiles in the vector have different costs depending on the moveability of the projectiles. Going from copying the projectile to move the projectile to constructing the projectile in place.

But there is an even faster method, namely reuse.

Construct all the projectiles before the game starts and then reuse the projectiles all the time.

Comment: I tried the reuse-way, but it gave me headache: Since I loop through all "active" projectiles each game tick, i would like to avoid checking if(projectile[i].active==true) for each projectile but instead to make the first "index x" elements active and adjust the x. If I would reuse and a projectile goes from active to not-active, i would first have to find its position in the vector (looping through all active elements), put it at the end of the vector, and adjust the position of each object with a higher index to -1. Would that really be efficient?

Comment: If you have 2 variables with the first being the first active projectile, and the second the last active. This would reduce the number of entries you would have to check. But also the size and composition of your projectile determine how fast it would be to move/copy it. Alternative you have have an vector with just the entry numbers of the active projectiles if they are large.